# angularjs 2 rc4 Change detection: expression changed after it was checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, expression, detection

After upgrading from rc1 to rc4 i get the following exception:

```
Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'
```

After researching this issue online and after reading all that i could, i still don't know how to correct this problem in an "angular" way (without timeouts etc).

- Helpful thread: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005

I understand that **when on dev mode change detection is run once more,** just to make sure that nothing has changed. I also understand that everything that changes a binding 'should trigger another round of change detection'.

**What i don't understand is *why*** a new round of detection is not automatically triggered when the event occurs and **how** to correct that.

I have a very simple use case. The top-most component is responsible for displaying the outer UI. It also contains a control that should be hidden/shown. This behaviour is controlled by the active route component.

Child instantiation happens by the active route (router-outlet) and not manually.

So this top-most component and all child components subscribe to an eventemitter inside a shared service and send events.

The top-most component also subscribes to this event on it's Oninit. When it receives the event, it changes a local variable. This is reflected on the html for this component.

**AppComponent**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  hidePageControls:boolean = true;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(): any {
    let me = this;

    this.apiService.hidePageControls.subscribe(value => me.hidePageControls = value);
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
ngOnInit() {
    me.apiService.hidePageControls.emit(false);
}
```

The rationale behind this is that when users navigate to different part of the app, different components are used. These components then send events to the top-most component to show/hide a specific control.

I have read of possible solutions to this problem including setTimeout(), directly invoking the change detection etc. People are also saying that we should not 'fight' the framework, with which i agree.

So please let me know if my thinking of a child component notifying a parent component is the 'wrong' way of thinking in angular, and by all means let me know of what the 'angular' way of doing this would look like.

---

**Edit**

The only solution i have found for this type of errors is to use a timeout as such:

Detach the change detector.
When the event is fired manually trigger a change detection round.

```
constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private categoryService: CategoryService, private router: Router, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.cd.detach();
}

.
.
.
.

this.apiService.hidePageControls.subscribe(value => {
    me.hidePageControls = value;
    setInterval(() => {
        me.cd.detectChanges();
    }, 100);
});
```

As i understand it, this will cause a change detection round *after* the additional development change detection run has finished because of the timeout. I find this to be a finicky solution.

Please let me know if a better one exists.

Comment: Any news about this issue? Have you found another way to deal with it or another way to build your services/components? Thanks!

Comment: I have not found any 'angular' way of doing this kind of thing. I have opted for the manual change detection and timeout as mentioned above. I will be waiting for the 1st release to look into this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using almost similar way to enable/disable control depending on child element decision.
Before angular update (rc1->rc4) it worked like a charm. After the update, components started to break on first load.
The breaking change is:

> facade: change EventEmitter to be sync by default (#8761) (e5904f4)

[link to issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6311)

Parent component values changes after its change detection round is finished during **initialization** of child component.

---

**Fix** for your problem may be:

```
// in apiService
hidePageControls = new EventEmitter(true);
```

True in EventEmitter constructor will force it to be async

Hope it'll help.

Comment: hidePageControls = new EventEmitter<boolean>(true); if you need it to be typed

Comment: This method of providing a value to the constructor seems to be working for me on rc4

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't like when change detection causes changes of the model.

`ngOnInit()` is called by change detection.

You can use `setTimeout()` to delay the change until change detection is completed. `setTimeout()` causes an application-wide change detection run and is therefore not advicable.

You can use another lifecycle callback that is not called by change detection

As far as I remember `ngAfterViewInit` works for this case.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    me.apiService.hidePageControls.emit(false);
}
```

Another way is to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call change detection explicitly to make Angular aware of the change before it throws:

```
constructor(cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
    me.apiService.hidePageControls.emit(false);
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```